Implementing Export/Import menu commands?
I have an import (and export) button(s) that works fine placed in a view.
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        isImporting = true
    }, label: {
        Label("Import", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.down")
    })
    .fileImporter(
        isPresented: $isImporting,
        allowedContentTypes: [UTType.log, UTType.text, UTType.xml, UTType.zip],
        allowsMultipleSelection: true
    ) { result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(files):
            files.forEach { file in
                guard file.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { return }
                    .../...
                file.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

But I also want import/export commands available via the File menu in the macOS application.
struct ImportExportCommands: Commands {
    @MainActor
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .importExport) {
            Section {
                ImportButton()
                    .modelContainer(mdContainer.sharedModelContainer)
                ExportButton()
                    .modelContainer(mdContainer.sharedModelContainer)
            }
        }
    }
}

The action code is executed, but no file dialog appears.
I didn't find anything about this so I suppose that is a very stupid thing.
How can I have fileImporter/fileExporter dialog pop up on the screen from a menu command?

I had this problem for a while and never find anything about it. But finally I have found this page:
".fileExporter and .fileImporter Won’t Work inside a Menu in SwiftUI"
https://fpposchmann.de/fileexporter-and-fileimporter-wont-work-inside-a-menu-in-swiftui/
Thanks to Frank-Peter for the idea.
I have reworked my code and now commands in the CommandGroup works as it should.
private struct FactorizedIExportButton: View {
    @Binding var isExporting: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isExporting = true
        }, label: {
            Label("Export…", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
        })
        .keyboardShortcut("E")
    }
}

struct ImportButton: View {
    @State var isImporting: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        FactorizedImportButton(isImporting: $isImporting)
            .fileImporter(
                isPresented: $isImporting,
                allowedContentTypes: [.text, .kmz],
                allowsMultipleSelection: true
            ) { result in importFiles(result) }
    }
}

struct ExportButton: View {
    @State var isExporting: Bool = false
    var document = TextDocument()

    var body: some View {
        FactorizedIExportButton(isExporting: $isExporting)
            .fileExporter(
                isPresented: $isExporting,
                document: document,
                contentTypes: [.gpx],
                defaultFilename: "Export"
            ) { result in exportFile(result) }
    }
}

struct ImportExportCommands: Commands {
    @State var isImporting: Bool = false
    @State var isExporting: Bool = false
    var document = TextDocument()

    @MainActor
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .importExport) {
            Section {
                FactorizedImportButton(isImporting: $isImporting)
                FactorizedIExportButton(isExporting: $isExporting)
            }
            .fileImporter(
                isPresented: $isImporting,
                allowedContentTypes: [.text, .kmz],
                allowsMultipleSelection: true
            ) { result in importFiles(result) }
            .fileExporter(
                isPresented: $isExporting,
                document: document,
                contentTypes: [.gpx],
                defaultFilename: "Export"
            ) { result in exportFile(result) }
        }
    }
}


The problem as I see it that you first need to open window for the .fileImporter modifier to work but one way to get around this is to use NSOpenPanel instead.
Something like this:
struct ImportExportCommands: Commands {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindows
    @MainActor
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .importExport) {
            Section {
                Button("Import") {
                    selectImportFiles()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func selectImportFiles() {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.title = "Import files"
        openPanel.prompt = "Import"
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        openPanel.allowedContentTypes = [UTType.log, UTType.text, UTType.xml, UTType.zip]

        openPanel.begin { result in
            if result == .OK {
                for fileUrl in openPanel.urls {
                    print(fileUrl.absoluteString)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I had a similar problem in a SwiftUI app. What worked for me was to add a focused binding to the menu views.
Adding a focused binding requires you to do the following:

Create a focused value key struct for the focused binding.
Create an extension to SwiftUI's FocusedValues struct for the focused value key you create.
Add a focused binding to the menu views.
Set the focused scene value in the app struct or a higher level view, such as the content view.

The focused value key struct must conform to the FocusedValueKey protocol. Provide a type alias for the focused value type. The following code creates a focused value type for a SwiftUI document struct:
struct DocumentFocusedValueKey: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = Binding<Document>
}

The FocusedValues extension's computed property requires you to add a getter and setter for the focused value key struct you create.
extension FocusedValues {
    var document: DocumentFocusedValueKey.Value? {
        get {
            return self[DocumentFocusedValueKey.self]
        }
        
        set {
            self[DocumentFocusedValueKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}

Use the @FocusedBinding property wrapper to add a focused binding to your menu views.
@FocusedBinding(\.document) var theDocument: Document?

The value you put after @FocusedBinding is the name of the computed property you added as an extension to FocusedValues.
Use the .focusedSceneValue modifier to set the focused scene value. The following example sets the focused scene's value to the document in a document-based app:
.focusedSceneValue(\.document, file.$document)

In this example you would set the .focusedSceneValue modifier in the app struct.
